# Crash while upgrading from 18.04LTS to 19.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, freeze

I was having random freezing of the 18.04 so as there was a new version available I decided to upgrade and hopefully resolve the issue.  I started the upgrade using the update manager and all appeared ok until about 80% of the way through the system froze and would not respond to any inputs.  My only choice was to crash the machine.

When I tried to restart it appears to be trying but it gets to the point where it displays Ubuntu 18.04 and about 6 dots under it.  Then the screen changes to just blue and after a minute it changes to black, this blue / black continues but nothing develops any further.  I have tried booting through the Recovery mode selection but it appears to get so far then stops.

I'd like to recover it if possible but failing that I guess I'll have to reload the whole thing.

Your advice would be appreciated.

Comment: A crash during release-upgrade is just about the worst thing that can happen, and may indeed render your system unbootable if it occurs at the wrong moment. Boot from a LiveUSB, Backup your data, then clean-install a fresh Ubuntu...and then start troubleshooting those pesky freezes.